# I want to load an in vue that has been by post request using flask and response is its path

Tags: javascript, html, image, vue.js, vue-component

I already have tried many methods available on StackOverflow. Most of them ask to use require.context that will load all images path and then use image path that I have got from post response.

But my problem lies here, I ask user to upload the Image then save it locally in assets folder, process the image and save output in assets folder.

This image name has to be unique, so I use uuid.uuid4() in python- which is completely random.

require.context cannot load my image path since it was not available at time when webpack was being complied, Hence the error - Cannot find module '../assets/9a5d60e2-4c2c-4fd9-a617-5dcdde4db6cc.jpg'.

```
<TwentyTwenty
        :before="getImgUrl(resp['original'])"
        :after="getImgUrl(resp['dreamed'])"
        beforeLabel='Orignal'
        afterLabel="Dreamed"
        keyboardStep=0.01 />

getImgUrl(pet) {
        var images = require.context('../assets/', false, /\.jpg$/)
        return images('' + pet + ".jpg")
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once your Vue application is built, there is no `assets` folder. You cannot `require` / `import` anything that doesn't exist at bundle-time.

What you should be doing is have your Python app save the uploaded images into a location that is accessible via HTTP (eg `static/uploads` or as you've indicated, your Flask app root).

You then just use a plain old, regular URL to display the image in your Vue app, eg

```
# .env file
VUE_APP_API_BASE=http://localhost:8080
```

```html
<TwentyTwenty
  :before="`${apiBase}/${resp.original}.jpg`"  
  :after="`${apiBase}/${resp.dreamed}.jpg)`"
  beforeLabel='Orignal'
  afterLabel="Dreamed"
  keyboardStep="0.01" />
```

```js
data: () => ({
  apiBase: process.env.VUA_APP_API_BASE, // get API base URL from .env
  resp: {
    // whatever
  }
})
```

Comment: Reply to Phil's answer - I don't have static folder, I have src folder that contains assets, components, plugin, router and views folder and App.vue and main.js file. How do I find my equivalent of static folder

Comment: @piyush it's your Flask app that handles the upload. Is it also serving the Vue app? Where does it currently save uploaded files to?

Comment: No my flask app dosen't serve my Vue app. It is run using on 8080. It saves images in my root folder which contains app, virtual environment and run.py file.

Comment: @piyush then you'd need to serve the images from your Flask app. I've updated my answer